# How do I replace my background when it runs out?

Tags: ios, swift, background, sprite-kit

```
var replacebg = SKAction.moveToY(bgTexture.size().height , duration: 0)
    var replacebgForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(replacebg)

    bg.runAction(replacebgForever)
```

Every touch on the screen moves the background down 50 pixels.  I want to replace the background when it runs out, using the same image. I have tried the above code, but it does not work and instead stops all my animations.  Any help? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `update` method in `SKScene`, you can reset the `background` back if goes out of the screen.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if bg.position.y + bg.size.height/2 < 0
    {
        bg.position.y = self.frame.height + bg.size.height/2

    }
}
```

To create a wrap around effect, create two background sprite nodes like the following. The two backgrounds are kept one above the other.

```
background1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
background1.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
background1.size.height = self.frame.height

background2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
background2.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+ self.frame.size.height)
background2.size.height = self.frame.height

self.addChild(background1)
self.addChild(background2)
```

Then in the `touchesBegan` function

```
if background1.position.y + background1.size.height/2 < 50
{
    let diff =  background1.position.y + background1.size.height/2 - 50
    background1.position.y = self.frame.height + background1.size.height/2 + diff
}
else
{
     background1.position.y -= 50
}
if background2.position.y + background2.size.height/2 < 50
{
    let diff =  background2.position.y + background2.size.height/2 - 50
    background2.position.y = self.frame.height + background2.size.height/2 + diff
}
else
{
    background2.position.y -= 50
}
```

The above code can be made more modular. But I leave that to you.